# Do Port/Online monsters have different drop rates?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I remember that in MHFU, the monsters encountered on Guild hunts were reputed to have higher drop rates for rarer materials (such as Rubies and Plates). I am not sure if this was true, but is this the case in MH3U? Do the Tanzia (Port) monsters have different drop rates than the Moga (Village) monsters?

Comment: The Brady Guide makes no distinction between Village and Port.  It does, however, point out freehunting has differing drop rates.

Comment: Honestly, this question is a big one because of the sheer time and statistics required to prove drop rates are different from one monster online to one offline. Out of personal experience I know that quest rewards can be different between online and off but the monsters are the same. I really only "know" this by experience. I have no proof, if you statistical proof, you might wanna up this bounty cause it's a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bradygames guide gives fixed percentages for monster drops at any given hunter rank. No mention is made of percentages varying by whether you play port or village.

Randomness is randomness though, so while some hunters grind for hours on end just to get that one Wyvern Stone to finis their armor set, others get Stones nearly every other quest despite having no idea what to do with so many.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same I played since monster hunter 2. The rates of drops differ by 1 percent, I have tested a theory in which case that if you die 2 times out of 3 and kill you will get significantly less than a guy who is 0 times out of 3. There's also the performance test I made on taking less damage than to more damage in the game your drops becomes more rarer if you take significantly less damage.

Now to answer your question they are the same if the ranking is low it is low as well but the requirements to get rarity is less demanding making it easier to get stuff on online since the game expects you to take more damage. You can try this on gold cedaeus I got 3 dark gems off the first try of taking only 1 mega potion in the game with unupgraded armor. I don't have proof to support my statements but performance brings results. If you can't perform as badass there's always the luck part or you could have both. :D

Comment: There's absolutely no evidence that shows better performance means you get better drops.

Comment: It`s by continuous playing against the monsters... the better you perform the better the drops I have played numerous times just improving my finishing time and the number of mistakes I make and I do see **much** more items than a regular fight. Ensure that you complete the objectives of breaking every piece of his body as well.

Comment: Rewards for breaking parts are a binary thing; you break the part, you get an extra item.  What evidence do you have that shows killing it faster, using less potions, or making less mistakes correlates to better items?  Without that, this just seems to be confirmation bias.